# SmoothDivScroll give me a blank div

Tags: jquery, smooth-scrolling

I am using the plug-in "[Smooth Div Scroll 1.2](http://www.smoothdivscroll.com/v1-2.htm)".

In my [website](http://www.martinandme.com/) I notice that when I scroll to the last post appears another empty/blank one. It seems to be a problem with the multiple container divs that I'm using to format the info inside of the post.

HTML code for each post:

```
<div id="makeMeScrollable">
    <div class="scrollableArea">
        <div class="wrapper">
            <img src="css/fake.png" data-src="images/media/myimage.jpg" width="486"  alt=""  />
            <div class="more">+</div>
            <div class="description">
                <div class="description_content">
                    A description here
                </div>
                <div class="social_icons">
                    <a href="#" data-share="#"><img src="images/share.png" alt="share in Facebook" /></a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And this is the example code used in the demo:

```
<div id="makeMeScrollable">
    <img src="images/demo/field.jpg" alt="Demo image" width="497" height="330" id="field" />
</div>
```

I don't know if this version handle another nested div, but this seems be the problem because I remove all the divs and just left the image and it works.

Thanks!

SOLUTION: Just put all inside of div.#makeMeScrollable, no other containers divs are allowed.

Comment: Exactly where do we start helping you when there is no code posted, should we all go to your (spanish) website and start searching blindly for errors?

Comment: @adeneo im not asking a traslation so please ... Im using this Jquery Plugin as example: http://www.smoothdivscroll.com/v1-2.htm my HTML code is above.

Comment: I may have been a bit harsh, but it's hard enough getting help for a plugin specific question such as his, and when only adding a generalt description and a link to site in a different language it's hard for others to figure out exactly where the problem is. I see you have added some code, but I still can't really spot any bugs, but maybe someone with experience from that particular plugin or someone with the time to look closer at your site can tell you what the problem is. If not, just try to rephrase your question a little better, add a jsFiddle etc. and ask again.

Comment: If you need more help, version 1.2 is now a formal release and all the documentation has been updated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLUTION: Just put all inside of div.#makeMeScrollable, no other "containers" divs are allowed. If you check the past version (1.1) others divs were needed, not in this brand new version who make it via JS.